# Any type of fluid is not working

Tags: particles, physics

I need to use fluid simulations in a project, so I've tried them out in some files and they work just fine, but when I try to apply any type of fluid physics in my project file it doesn't work at all, I don't know if the problem is in a setting or in the file overall. Here is the file [FluidNotWorking.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNOmplixFC6JthgFtYZ6xMMI7Hu_zS8s/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT: I've found out that if I move the file to the desktop it suddenly works, nonetheless it keeps failing when I place it in my project folder, now I'm even more confused than before

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds himself in the same situation.The problem was the cache folder that the domain was baking on, still have no clue why it wasn't finding it, but anyways, I solved it by just changing the cache folder to one in another location and it did the trick